# How can I cleanup the HiveMQ message cache dir?

Tags: java, hivemq

I found those two folders are growing up pretty fast, and it seems there is no way to clean it up.

```
/opt/hivemq/data/persistence/publish_payload_store


/opt/hivemq/data/persistence/retained_messages
```

I set message (or conn) with following attributes:

```
qos(MqttQos.EXACTLY_ONCE)
retain(false)
cleanStart(true)
keepAlive(60)
sessionExpiryInterval(60)
```

HiveMQ version : HiveMQ CE 2020.2 with MQTT5

Comment: I got the answer : https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-community-edition/issues/183